# Basic EventSource and SSE example

Tags: html, jquery, tomcat, jquery-events

A question about Serve-Side Events and EventSource.
This is my simple page (listener.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<title>SSE test page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      var guid = "1234567890";
      var source = new EventSource('servlet/push-event');
      source.onmessage = function (e) {
          alert(e.origin);
      };    
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>Listener!</body>
</html>
```

and is deployed beyond Tomcat so I access it with (http://127.0.0.1:8080/html/listener.html)

I implemented the server side in Java:

```
resp.setContentType("text/event-stream");
resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
PrintWriter out;
try {
    out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write("data: wowowowowowo");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I call listener.html in Firefox and in Android 4 native browser I see the alerts in succession as if the event was fired from elsewhere but I don't know where.

Other browser like IE9 or Chrome have no response.

Where is the problem? Me, Tomcat or browser?

Comment: If you are using a browser, then your java on tomcat should be uing a httpresponsewriter, so that all the http header information is included. The browser (whatever it is) may not work without it. That being said, if you have chrome, you should open up the debug tools and see if you get anything at all. Also, try it without the javascript to try and isolate the problem :) - Good question by the way :)

Comment: seems problem was me, 

I would've expected only alert when in some way the event was fired, but really browsers polling server. In fact if I shut down the server there is another call before connection were closed.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Luca